# UIImagePickerController camera view: height of the black bottom bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, camera-overlay

I see that by default, when displaying a `UIImagePickerController` with type `camera`, a black bar at the bottom of screen appears at the bottom.

I'd like to show a custom `cameraOverlayView` exactly on top and matching the dimensions of such black bottom bar, but I don't find a way of getting its height.

**EDIT:** alternatively, how could I calculate a `cameraViewTransform` keeping the aspect ratio of the camera view in such way the black bottom will have a certain height I can choose?

**EDIT 2:** Is that black bottom the same height for all devices?

Answer (score 0):

I Was facing same issue please use below code.

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
            let aspectRatio:CGFloat = 4.0/4.0
            let scale = screenSize.height/screenSize.width * aspectRatio
            imagePickers!.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale);
```